run node js program which uses puppeteer from a php script
I have a php code test1.php
<?php
    $command = "node node1.mjs";
     //Execute the Node.js script
    $output = shell_exec($command);

    // Display the output
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>

and this is my node1.mjs program
    import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
(async () => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Set viewport width and height
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720 });

  const website_url = 'https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-convert-html-into-pdf-with-node-js-and-puppeteer/';
  await page.goto(website_url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

  // Capture screenshot
  await page.screenshot({
    path: '/tmp/screenshot_1.jpg',
  });
 console.log('Screenshot Taken');
  await browser.close();
})();

When i run php from command line using php test1.php it takes the screenshot and stores it in tmp and prints the following

Screenshot Taken 

But when i run this php file from browser it prints the following
Screenshot Taken
but does not take the screenshot.(MEANING THERE IS NO SCREENSHOT1_JPG IN /TMP DIRECTORY) There are no errors in console or in logs. what can be the issue?

Related post: run a node js program from php works fine when run in terminal, but has no effect when triggered from browser. What do you mean by "does not take the screenshot"? Do you mean the code runs, but the screenshot doesn't appear in the expected directory? Is this a [mcve]? I don't have your username and password, so I can't really run this, which makes it hard to reproduce the problem. If you can create a version that has the same behavior without the auth...

@ggorlen, I have updated the codes in the question to take a simple screenshot of a website without any username and password. This does its work from command line but when run from broswer all console messages appear in browser but there is no scrrenshot captured and saved in /tmp directory

Thanks for minimizing. I ran the code on Ubuntu 22.04, PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14, Puppeteer 22.6.0, Node 20.11.1 and it worked fine for me, saved a screenshot to /tmp when I visited localhost:8000 (I ran php -S localhost:8000 test1.php to serve).

Node version : v18.19.1, ubuntu 20.04.2, puppeteer 18.1.0, i have my php code stored in var/www/html so that i can access it from browser, and i run it just by accessing my broswerurl/test1.php and the o/p is displayed as Screenshot Taken but no image in temp. am i going wrong with the way i run the php from the browser?

when i run curl http://localhost/puppeteer-new/test1.php
from the command line i get Node  version : v18.19.1
Node path : /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.1/bin/node
User : rootScreenshot Taken

but no image in /tmp

localhost/puppeteer-new/test1.php is missing a port. But assuming you have one, those versions should work fine as well. Regardless of curl or browser access, the screenshot should be written. Not sure what the issue is. If you didn't have write access, I expect the .screenshot() function would throw. Maybe try a different directory, like the current working directory.

Its on port 80 , and if the problem was with the port i shud have got a 404 or some error on the webpage, it is printing the statments from the node js script. and i tried other directories too. but still isn't working. i have used the same versions as yours.

even if i try to create a file using fs import fs from 'fs';
//const fs =  require('fs');
// File path where you want to create/save the file
const filePath = '/tmp/example.txt';
// Content you want to write to the file
const fileContent = 'Hello, this is some content for the file.';
// Write content to the file
fs.writeFile(filePath, fileContent, (err) => {
if (err) {
console.error('Error writing to file:', err);
} else {
console.log('File created and saved successfully!');
}
});
from the broswer it prints all the stuff in node program but doesnt save it.

Figured it out finally. it was a problem with /tmp directory. There was no error though.  But when i created a directory sudo mkdir /var/www/php-files
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/php-files
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/php-files and write the image in this directory it worked

Great! Feel free to post a self answer.
